# Fail to deploy contract on rinkeby using truffle and metamask

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, truffle, metamask

Following is a snippet from my truffle-config.js file

```
  networks: {
    // Useful for testing. The `development` name is special - truffle uses it by default
    // if it's defined here and no other network is specified at the command line.
    // You should run a client (like ganache-cli, geth or parity) in a separate terminal
    // tab if you use this network and you must also set the `host`, `port` and `network_id`
    // options below to some value.
    //
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    },

    rinkeby: {
      provider: function () {
        return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3*************************************");
      },
      from: "0xe95745a8F4E3cDb1cF5bfFD4A94F0B249e99f489",
      network_id: 4,
      gas: 4500000,
      gasPrice: 10000000000,
    }
```

I am trying to deploy my contract on rinkeby using an address generated by metamask. However when I run `truffle migrate --network rinkeby` It gives me the following error:

```
C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\provider\index.js:56
        throw new Error(errorMessage);
^
Error: There was a timeout while attempting to connect to the network.
       Check to see that your provider is valid.
       If you have a slow internet connection, try configuring a longer timeout in your Truffle config. Use the networks[networkName].networkCheckTimeout property to do this.
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\provider\index.js:56:1)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
```

Any suggestions why this might be happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. It was a typo. Missed a bracket after v3 in the provider link
https://rinkeby.infura.io/v36c... was changed to https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/6c....

Comment: Don’t share ur infura Projekt id here